# Writing Test cases for Spring Integration Application

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-integration, integration-testing

I am new for Unit/Integration testing. Hence looking for best approach for given scenario.
I have legacy application (REST) which was written in Spring Integration. Same application I have migrated to Spring Boot. Now I am wondering, how to mock Gateway in Controller and how to test Gateways, Routers. Application structure as:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/acct")
public class AcctOpenImpl implements AcctOpen {
    /**
     * AcctMgmt Gateway Interface.
     */
    @Autowired
    AcctOpenService acctopenmgmtServiceGateway;
    
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product/{product_id_num}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<RetrieveAppProdAplnResponse> rtrvAppProdAplnByQueryParam(
        @PathVariable("product_id_num") final Long productIdNum) throws BusinessException,
        TechnicalException {
        Map<String, Object> headers = getHeaders();
       
        RetrieveAppProdAplnResponse response = this.acctopenmgmtServiceGateway.rtrvAppProdApln(request, headers);

        ResponseEntity<RetrieveAppProdAplnResponse> retrieveAppProdResponse = new ResponseEntity<RetrieveAppProdAplnResponse>(
            response, HttpStatus.OK);

        return retrieveAppProdResponse;
    }
}
```

**Service Interface:**

```
public interface AcctOpenService {
    public RetrieveAppProdAplnResponse rtrvAppProdApln(RetrieveAppProdAplnRequest retrieveAppProdAplnRequest,
        @Headers Map<String, Object> customHeaderMap) throws BusinessException, TechnicalException;
}
```

**geteways.xml:**

```
<int:gateway id="acctopenmgmtServiceGateway" service-interface="com.hsbc.group.depositproduct.svc.gateway.AcctOpenService"
    default-reply-channel="acctopenmgmtReplyChannel" error-channel="acctopenmgmtErrorChannel">
    <int:method name="rtrvAppProdApln" request-channel="rtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel" />
</int:gateway>
```

**si-channels.xml:**

```
<int:channel id="rtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel"/>
```

**si-routers.xml:**

```
<int:router input-channel="rtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel" default-output-channel="acctopenmgmtReplyChannel"     expression="headers.SERVICE_HEADER.consumerEntyId.ctryCde.toLowerCase()+headers.SERVICE_HEADER.consumerEntyId.groupMbr+'RtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel'" />
```

**si-chain.xml:**

```
<int:chain input-channel="usMMBIRtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel" output-channel="acctopenmgmtReplyChannel">
    <int:transformer method="formatRequest" ref="usRtrvAppProdAplnTransformer"/>
    <int:service-activator method="rtrvAppProdApln" ref="rtrvAppProdAplnActivator" />
    <int:transformer method="parseResponse" ref="usRtrvAppProdAplnTransformer"/>
</int:chain>
```

**si-transformers.xml:**

```
<bean id="usRtrvAppProdAplnTransformer" class="com.hsbc.group.depositproduct.us.svc.transformer.RetrieveAppProdAplnTransformer">
</bean>
```

Could you please suggest best approach (Unit testing or Integration testing) for given scenario. Also, if some one gives any example that how can I start that will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully clear what you would like to test, but it feels more like you want to test really that REST call. Consider to investigate what is Spring Mock MVC, plus some feature from Spring Boot:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-rest-templates-test-utility

Comment: Thanks for your reply. actually I want to test my REST APIs but I am wondering how to test Gateways, Routers.

Comment: The gateway is nothing more than just a plain service to inject into a test case and call. The router has that `rtrvAppProdAplnRequestChannel` as a input to send messages. See more info in Spring Integration docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing